# Ubuntu 14.04 only has 2 ways to display my folders. Can I get the other option back?

Tags: directory

In Ubuntu 12.04 I had 3 choices of displaying my folders but now I have upgraded to 14.04 and there are only 2 choices to display my folders.

I don't like 'icon' view and I don't like 'list' where one folder is on top of the other.
I like the folders to fill the whole window, on top of each other but also to the sides just like I had it in 12.04.

Is there anything I can do to get my preferrd folder view back?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the Compact view:

[image]

Then no, not using the default file browser, Nautilus.

You can install [Nemo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/nemo/), which does retain this option:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

You can set Compact view as the default. Go to the *Edit* menu, then click on *Preferences*:

[image]

Set *View new folders using:* to *Compact View*.

Comment: Ah yes, that's worked great. Thanks. Now just need to figure out how to make compact the default.

Comment: @user308639 I have updated the answer for that.